# 48 minute technique for entering and sustaining programmer flow

Tags: workflow

I have been working at entering and sustaining periods of flow while working, and while researching the concept I came across [this site](http://www.thatvoodooyoudo.com/best-practice/flow/) which addressed the idea of sustaining flow in short bursts. The technique specifies that one sets a timer for 48 minutes in which they focus purely on their work, and when the timer runs out they spend 12 minutes doing whatever.

However, in the paragraph directly above that statement is a quote from [Peopleware](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0932633439) saying that it takes at least 15 uninterrupted minutes to enter a state of flow.

When reading that point, the 48 minute technique seemed counter-intuitive, since every 48 minutes you are "breaking" your flow, and once you start up again you have to spend 15 minutes going back into it, so you really only get (at a maximum) 33 minutes of "flow time". Obviously these quantities aren't necessarily rigid, but you get the idea.

My question is to those who have tried a timing technique similar to the one described. As I see it, the only justification for this technique is that it possibly reduces the amount of time it takes to re-enter that period of flow. Can anyone who has used this technique provide some clarification?

Comment: That sounds similar to the http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/ approach.

Comment: @Paul Very interesting. That actually hits even more strongly on the point of interrupting flow time, since you are taking breaks after shorter periods of time. Would be interested to hear some personal experience stories.

Comment: I usually need to take a 10-minute "context switch" after an hour or so of intense coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the [Pomodoro Technique](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/) for a week or so. I didn't focus too much on the details of maintaining check lists of completed and interrupted sprints, but rather I started the day with the tasks that I wanted to do on that day, and went through them as best as I could using the 25-minute sprints and five-minute breaks.

The Pomodoro Technique suggests to use the breaks to relax, stretch your legs, grab a coffee, etc. I've noticed that activities like those that don't require a total focus shift and can be done on automatic don't break the flow, but rather helped me cleanse my mind and refocus my attention. It's as if you're allowing yourself to step away from the trees to survey the forest for a bit before diving back in.

I dropped Pomodoro after that short trial period because I found that in my case I got the most benefit from simply sitting down in the morning and writing down what I wanted to do on that day. Once the decision is made and the work is started I found that I fall into a natural rhythm of sorts. I work until I'm bored, frustrated, or interrupted, then I take a break and continue. I didn't find that time boxing my sprints added much value.

YMMV, but it's worth at least giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

A timer would be terrible for me, because it might go off and interrupt my train of thought at a critical moment.

For me, maximizing flow would begin by (1) first preventing forthcoming distractions (ie, making sure phone calls and other interrupts are disabled and that anything scheduled, like a meeting, is sufficiently far off there's no possibility of running into it), then (2) working on the problem at hand as long as I can, but all the while trying to recognize when I'm not making progress.

If I think I'm making progress, no matter how slowly, I just keep going as long as I can.  But if I appear to be stuck or going in circles, I stop, and do something else instead, even if that something else is starting on a different problem.  I let my subconscious dwell on the original problem, and once I have a feeling I feel fresh or curious enough to restart again, I do.